# Hide page URL but keep page number in print footer in google chrome Print Preview with JavaScript / CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome, printing

I am struggling to add page numbers in footer for my html page print via js/css.

After looking at several options like pagedjs.js, weasyprint etc. , I decided to use default page number option which comes when we click show header & footer option in chrome print preview.

Is there a way I can only show page numbers in footer section of print while printing a document from google chrome print preview?

I know that headers & Footers can be hide from settings menu in chrome print settings.

Also it can be hide by setting page margin to 0.

but I am looking for an option where **I only need to hide Page URL not page number**

[image]